# What are features generators in natural language processing

Tags: nlp

Can anyone tell me what feature generators are with respect to natural language processors?

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific - what NLP task are you asking about? The types of features selected and how they are generated are task-dependent. And NLP has many tasks.

Comment: The exact quote is:

"You have to train the name finder yourself on your data to get better results. With your own training data you can even use the html tags and optimize the feature generation."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm reading this correctly, I believe "feature generation" in this quote is referring to the process of extracting features from your text.   Without going into too much detail this is basically getting the dimensions of your data you think would be useful for your prediction/classification task and putting it into a vector representation.

For example, suppose we were trying to create a classifier to determine if an e-mail was spam. We might extract features such as `CONTAINS_WORD_NIGERIA` or `IS_FROM_PERSON_IN_CONTACT_LIST`.  Or if we were to follow the quote above we might make specialized features using the html tags such as `PERCENT_OF_WORDS_IN_HREF_TAG`.  As you might imagine, you can go overboard when feature engineering, and the real challenge lies is in optimizing your feature set to give you good results on unseen data.